# using VBA to show comments of a cell, where comments are active Bloomberg formulae

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I am trying to create a 'comment' in excel that will show Bloomberg BDP info of whatever cell is highlighted.  For example, let's say active.cell = IBM and I 'hover' over IBM.  I would want a comment box to pop up showing relevant market data.

```
$bid = "=BDP(active.cell &" US EQUITY","BID_ALL_SESSION")"
$bidsize = "=BDP(active.cell &" US EQUITY","BID_SIZE_ALL_SESSIONS_RT")"
$ask = "=BDP(active.cell &" US EQUITY","ASK_ALL_SESSION")"
$asksize = "=BDP(active.cell &" US EQUITY","ASK_SIZE_ALL_SESSIONS_RT")"
$last = "=BDP(active.cell &" US EQUITY","LAST_ALL_SESSIONS")"
$lastsize = "=BDP(active.cell &" US EQUITY","TRADE_SIZE_ALL_SESSION_RT")"
```

in 'blah' I would want ($bidsize $bid $ask $asksize $last $lastsize)

I started peeking around and found something below, but do not know how to implement.  Any ideas?

```
Sub add-comments()

Dim rcell As Range

For Each rcell In Range("B2:B48")

If rcell.Value <> "" Then
rcell.AddComment

rcell.Comment.Text 'blah'
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Thanks for viewing

Comment: Do you want the comments to be "live"?

Comment: You can use the SelectionChange event in conjunction with the Bloomberg VBA API. But fetching the info from the API will probably take a bit of time, making your spreadsheet slow. Excel is probably not the best environment to do what you want.

Comment: Yes, I would like the comments to be "live".  As far as using Excel, my "real estate" is limited and most of the screens are used to display my spreadsheet.  I could easily toggle between excel and Bloomberg but I would rather leave the spreadsheet in the front.  Also, since I am already pulling this information on another worksheet I could always use an INDEX,MATCH function too.

Comment: @CMR72 That would probably be significantly faster. If I were you, I would ask a new question saying: I have some data in a sheet and need to use it to populate a comment when a cell is selected on another sheet - make sure you show the code you have tried and I'm sure someone will answer. No need to mention Bloomberg as some users might skip the question because they don't know Bloomberg.

Answer (score 0):

The comment in the commentbox of the cell is string and static. It cannot work the same way with the formula so that it cannot be "live". As I know, you can add a namerange control to this worksheet if you want to implement your idea. It has the selection event so you can add a comment based on the formula in the cell when the user selects one cell.